# How WP protects from password hijacking from random_password hook?

Tags: wordpress, security, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm new to WP and looking into the source code of the `wp_generate_password` function is calling hook `random_password`.

Doesn't this introduce high-security vulnerability? What is stopping me from creating a plugin that does something useful for the user but also registers a hook that hijacks the password?

For example something like this

```
add_filter( 'random_password', 'my_random_password' );
 
function my_random_password($password) {
    // send the password together with globals to my server. Global could contain the email or username of the user in which case the account is compromised.
    return $password;
}
```

Comment: I think you can use wp_generate_password() or random_password. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/random_password/ . Use the bool $extra_special_chars with true. It's a salt.

Comment: I believe this is a valid question and would like to know more about it. Ofcourse this is only when users password are auto-generated. If you are using a wordpress plugin repository  they are well are reviewed against the guidelines. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#the-guidelines And if you are using the plugin from untrusted sources you always have a chance of introducing security flaws. I suppose review will check if you are sending something to a global server or not. I may be wrong.